# Integration of Partial Fraction Expansion

Tags: partial-fractions

Hi This is my first time posting a question on this website. Thank you advance for helping me out here.

My question is

Suppose the density of $X$ is $$f(x) = \frac{Kx^2}{(1 + x)^5}$$ when $x > 0$. Find the
constant $K$ and the density of $Y = \frac{1}{(1 + X)}$.

++one more thing since this is pdf. This equals to 1.

I tried partial fraction expansion to do it but it was long and didn't lead to answer. For the density part I finished upto $\frac{-Kx^2}{(x+1)^3}$. However, I do not know K and could not finish it.

Thank you again

Comment: $f(x) = Kx^2=(1 + x)^5$?

Comment: sorry its Kx^2/(1+x)^5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use $u$-sub first to get
\begin{align}
\int \frac{Kx^2}{(1+x)^5}\ dx = \int \frac{K(u-1)^2}{u^5}\ du.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks I will try and get back to you!

Comment: sorry what is happening to K? because I approach same thing when K is not present before substitution.

Comment: so with K added in, I still need to use partial fraction expansion right?

Comment: OH I think it i got it now. make them separate and integrate them one by one

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Hi Jack, I got k=12 for my answer. Thank you!